# Improve Flagging Options

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, flags

For folks who do not have the ability to vote to close questions for specific reasons, you are left with few options.  You can add a comment with a link to the duplicate, but if you review the flag options, there really doesn't seem to be a good fit for something like flagging as a duplicate.

I certainly wouldn't use Hate Speech and think flagging for needing moderator attention is rather broad.

Would it be possible to add a text entry next to the needs attention selection or potentially add a duplicate option on the flag menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's unclear what the flag link actually does. There should be a visual cue indicating that you'll be prompted for a specific option.

I agree that you should be able to include a duplicate link.

Answer (score 3):

Select "requires moderator attention" and there will be a text entry box.  You can use that to narrow down specifically what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks... Hadn't gone that far!

Answer (score 1):

Leaving a comment is fine. That is the preferred course of action. No flag is necessary, someone will get to it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to enter the duplicate link would be good, then have a button the moderator could hit that would autoload the duplicate link in a standard format.