# Ability to view all tags in user profile

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

I had asked the question [How to view all tags in user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45585/how-to-view-all-tags-in-user-profile) but the answer seems to be no. So I'll make a feature request.

This may be arranged just like the view of all of the questions and answers of a user which are shown by clicking the number tabs. So we can view all tags on which we're active (50 tags per tab).

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: I deliberately wrote "Feature request for viewing all tags in user profile" in order to distinguish this question from the other question, which is "How to view all tags in user profile". After your edit, both question titles are the same, which doesn't seem right to me. I'm taking my chance to rollback.

Comment: Don't use tags in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: You're right, but keep in mind that question titles are at least as important as tags.

Comment: You may want to edit other questions with "Feature request" in title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4817/feature-request-improve-flagging-options ; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5088/feature-request-display-accepted-questions-first ; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9100/feature-request-enhancing-sites-with-microformats ; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10053/feature-request-back-to-top-links-on-answers ; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/feature-request-delete-inside-first-20-minutes-should-permanently-delete ,etc.

Comment: @Meh: Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: No problem. You're welcome.